# Not able to read the data in the particular column in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

> I have a grid view with mysql connection. In which i am not able to read the updated column value in a GridView.
>   [image]
>
> I tried with the following aspx code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#2A3F54" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataKeyNames="order_id"                 unat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" Height="100%" CellSpacing="30" CellPadding="50"
    OnRowEditing="GridView_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>                                 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="order_id" HeaderText="SL NO" ItemStyle-Width="80" ItemStyle-Height="40" />                                               
        <asp:BoundField DataField="order_date" HeaderText="ORDER DATE" DataFormatString = "{0:d}" ApplyFormatInEditMode = "true" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="customer_id" HeaderText="CUSTMORE NAME" ItemStyle-Width="140"  />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="order_amt" HeaderText="AMOUNT" ItemStyle-Width="100" />                                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="updated_on" HeaderText="LAST UPDATED" DataFormatString = "{0:d}" ApplyFormatInEditMode = "true" ItemStyle-Width="130" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="REMARKS" ItemStyle-Width="130" />         
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />                   
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="True" HeaderText="ACTION" ItemStyle-Width="100">
        <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="onViewClick">View</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                      
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

> Please find the below c# code:

```
 protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");

        TextBox oderAmt = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];

        string orderAmount = oderAmt.Text;         
        string Query = @"update app_order_master set order_amt="+ orderAmount+" where order_id=1";

        using (DataTable dt = SMSDBHelperFE.ExecuteReaderDataTable(CommandType.Text, Query, null))
        {               
            GridView.DataSource = dt;
            GridView.DataBind();
        }

          GridView.EditIndex = -1;         
        gvBind();
       }
```

See the image above i am not able read the **amount** value which i need to update now.

Comment: Try using row.FindControl() to get value of amount column

Comment: @AA how we need to do that we don't have any label to define that we have only Boundfield for that

Comment: try adding template field instead of bound field. Put a textbox inside edit item template